# Adding postgresql jar though spark-submit on amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I've tried spark-submit with --driver-class-path, with --jars as well as tried this method https://petz2000.wordpress.com/2015/08/18/get-blas-working-with-spark-on-amazon-emr/

On using SPARK_CLASSPATH in the commandline as in

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH=/home/hadoop/pg_jars/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar pyspark
```

I get this error

```
Found both spark.executor.extraClassPath and SPARK_CLASSPATH. Use only the former.
```

But I'm not able to add it. How do I add postgresql JDBC jar file to use it from pyspark? I'm using EMR version 4.2

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Clear environment variable:

```
unset SPARK_CLASSPATH
```

2) Use --jars option to distribute postgres driver over your cluster:

```
pyspark --jars=/home/hadoop/pg_jars/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar
//or
spark-submit --jars=/home/hadoop/pg_jars/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar <your py script or app jar>
```

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy. I solved it yesterday by directly adding the jar path to '/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf'. I will give your solution a shot next time I need to add a jar.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the jar path to `/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` at the `spark.driver.extraClassPath` row solved my issue.

Comment: Use Vitaliy's solution. Mine works just for stand-alone.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the approach bellow and works fine.

1) Step 1: Download postgres driver jar with bootstrap action shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /home/hadoop/lib/
cd /home/hadoop/lib

wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.12.jar
chmod +x postgresql-42.2.12.jar
```

2) Step 2: Add configuration JSON on cluster EMR setup to include jar file into executor and driver extraClassPath of spark-defaults file:

```
{
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
        "spark.executor.extraClassPath": ":/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/s3select/lib/emr-s3-select-spark-connector.jar:/home/hadoop/lib/postgresql-42.2.12.jar",
        "spark.driver.extraClassPath": ":/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/s3select/lib/emr-s3-select-spark-connector.jar:/home/hadoop/lib/postgresql-42.2.12.jar",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your EMR cluster has access to the internet, you can use Maven:

```
$ spark-sql --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.18 --driver-class-path ~/.ivy2/jars/org.postgresql_postgresql-42.2.18.jar
```

where `spark-sql` could be replaced by `pyspark` or another Spark CLI

This will download the PostgreSQL JDBC driver and dependencies from [Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/) to your EMR Master, most likely at `/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/` (you can look at the spark console / logs to double-check), and also load that driver into Spark