# Amazon EMR w/ Spark w/ Postgres: "Failed to start database 'metastore_db'"

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I've used Apache Spark with the PostgreSQL JDBC driver on my own Linux servers before without issues, but I can't get it to work on Amazon EMR doing it the same way.

I first downloaded the Postgres driver and set up my pyspark classpath this way: [Adding postgresql jar though spark-submit on amazon EMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130780/adding-postgresql-jar-though-spark-submit-on-amazon-emr)

I executed the following in `pyspark` on an Amazon EMR instance set up with Spark, similarly to how I usually do it on my own server. "myhost" is the hostname of my Amazon RDS instance running PostgreSQL, which I am able to connect to from my EMR instance with `psql`, so I know it should work:

```
# helper, gets RDD from database
def get_db_rdd(table, lower=0, upper=1000):
    db_connection = {
            "host": "myhost",
            "port": 5432,
            "database": "mydb",
            "user": "postgres",
            "password": "mypassword"
            }
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://{}:{}/{}?user={}".format(db_connection["host"],
                                                      db_connection["port"],
                                                      db_connection["database"],
                                                      db_connection["user"])
    ret = sqlContext \
        .read \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table) \
        .option("partitionColumn", "id") \
        .option("numPartitions", 1024) \
        .option("lowerBound", lower) \
        .option("upperBound", upper) \
        .option("password", db_connection["password"]) \
        .load()
    ret = ret.rdd
    return ret

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

rdd = get_db_rdd("test", 0, 3) # table exists, has columns (`id bigserial, string text`)
```

I immediately get a crash with this exception:

```
17/04/21 19:34:07 ERROR Schema: Failed initialising database.
Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@3aa157b0, see the next exception for details.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
[...]
```

Looking around online, this has to do with Apache Hive... No idea why that's involved here, but I may be misunderstanding. I do see `metastore_db` in my home dir. All the proposed solutions involve editing some Hive configuration that I don't even have on my instance or creating that dir I already have. My EMR instance has totally default settings. Could someone more familiar with this environment point me in the right direction?

Edit: I don't have the entire stack trace handy but have some left in my GNU screen. Here's more, mentions Derby:

```
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@3aa157b0, see the next exception for details.
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
        ... 113 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/hadoop/metastore_db.
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
```

Edit 2: Using other RDDs like the following works: `sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3]).map(lambda r: r * 2).collect()`. The problem is only for RDDs connected to Postgres.

Edit 3:

```
>>> spark.range(5).show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+
```

Comment: "Failed to start database 'metastore_db'" usually happens when you've got one instance of Spark already running and given the default metastore uses  Derby under the covers hence the exception. Could you post the entire stack trace? I expect errors from Derby down the bottom of the stack trace.

Comment: Yes, I see errors from Derby. But I only had one instance of Spark running as far as I know. On Monday, I'll try again and also capture the entire stack trace.

Comment: Getting better! Think we can sort it out soon. I'm sure you'll get the very same stack trace when you simply `spark-shell` and execute `spark.range(5).show` and the Spark underlying infrastructure gets booted up.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up trying it today and don't think that's the issue. If I just do something like `sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3]).map(lambda r: r * 2).collect()`, it works and returns a result. Only has issues when the JDBC driver gets involved in my Postgres-sourced RDD function. Here's the entire traceback (it's big): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/15775cc6fea23bad63150a7f30b091ab

Comment: I think that the way I'm setting up the Postgres connection, it's trying to connect again to my `metastore_db` for some reason, but my Spark instance is already using it, so it throws an exception.

Comment: "I ended up trying it today and don't think that's the issue" a false thinking I'd say. It does not bring SparkSession up and hence no metastore in use. Please execute `spark.range(5).show` as I asked for earlier.

Comment: How do you start the Spark application? pyspark? spark-submit?

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

> Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/hadoop/metastore_db.

tells us that the embedded, one-thread Derby instance is already in use. I'm not very familiar with Hive, but is used when Spark boots Hive-enabled `SparkSession` that you can see in your stack trace:

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.read(SQLContext.scala:516)
```

I copied the most relevant lines (to remove the noise).

Side note: You don't really need Hive features these days since Spark supports most natively (and in Spark 2.2 most Hive "infrastructure" [will get away](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/142f6d14928c780cc9e8d6d7749c5d7c08a30972)).

As you can see in the stack trace, the multiple-threads-accessing-single-threaded-Derby exception will only be thrown when you use `SparkSession` which is the entry point to Spark SQL.

```
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.read(SQLContext.scala:516)
```

That's why you don't see it when working with RDD API. The RDD API does not use Hive at all.

Read up Hive's official documentation at [Local/Embedded Metastore Database (Derby)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin#AdminManualMetastoreAdmin-Local/EmbeddedMetastoreDatabase(Derby)).

Comment: Yes, problem is Amazon includes Hive by default in their build/config. It seems that I can avoid the problem if I disable Hive or disconnect the default connection before I set up my SQLContext for Postgres. Documentation doesn't suggest any way to do this. I tried `del sqlContext` to make the original Hive context `pyspark` creates disconnect, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to suggestions from Jacek about the nature of my problem, I developed a hack workaround after some trial and error. Haven't been able to really solve the problem yet, but this works, and that's good enough for me. I'll report back if I run into problems later.

1. Start pyspark with the Postgres driver as normal:`pyspark --driver-class-path=/home/hadoop/postgres_driver.jar --jars=/home/hadoop/postgres_driver.jar`
2. While that's open (!), in a separate SSH session, cd to home and `mv metastore_db old_metastore_db` (or you can do this in pyspark with `os.system()`). The point of this is to release the lock on the metastore that Spark creates by default; Spark will recreate the directory without a lock.
3. Try to create an RDD connected to Postgres the way I described in my question. It'll give an error about "no suitable driver." For some reason, the driver wasn't loaded. But after that error, it seems the driver is actually loaded now.
4. `mv metastore_db old_metastore_db2`, for similar reasons to above. I guess another Hive session is connected now and needs its lock to be cleared out.
5. Create the Postgres-connected RDD again, same way. Driver is loaded, and metastore is unlocked, and it seems to work. I can fetch from my tables, perform RDD operations, and `collect()`.

Yes, I know this is very dirty. Use at your own risk.